# Logarithmic Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How does one go about solving:

$(5x+2)^{\frac{4}{3}} = 16$

I'm confused as how to parse through the equation to solve it using logs.

Comment: take the 3/4 power in both sides $ (5x+2)= 16^{3/4}=8 $ (use calculator) :)  then $ 5x=8-2 $ and $ x=6/5 $

Comment: You don't use logs; use logs only when you have a variable in the exponent, as in $2^{2x+5}=100$ or something like that (you really don't need a calculator either for this problem ;)

Comment: Every comment and solution assumed the power was $\frac 43$ so I edited to make it so. If this is wrong, please let me know what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&(5x+2)^{\frac{4}{3}} = 16\\\implies
&5x+2 = (16)^{\frac{3}{4}}\\\implies
&5x+2 = (2^4)^{\frac{3}{4}}\\\implies
&5x+2 = 2^3\\\implies
&5x+2 = 8\\\implies
&5x= 6\\\implies
&x=\frac{6}{5}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$(5x+2)^{\frac{4}{3}} = 16$$
$$\left((5x+2)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{4}} = 16^{\frac{3}{4}}$$
$$(5x+2)^{\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{4}}=2^{4\cdot \frac{3}{4}}$$
$$5x+2=2^3$$
$$5x+2=8$$
$$x=\frac{6}{5}$$